# VBA: Saving Excel form state

Tags: excel, forms, vba, state

I have noticed that some of the Excel Add-ins maintain state from one use to another. An example of this is the Solver add-in which will maintain form data even after closing and reopening the Excel spreadsheet.

Where are the form elements saved such that the form can maintain state? I'm interested in emulating this behavior in a custom add-in and have not been able to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Didn't look into this too much (maybe there's a better way to do this out there), but you're looking for serialization, I think. Check out http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21472 and  http://www.vb-helper.com/tut5.htm maybe it'll help get your started....

Comment: Cache in the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.runtime.cachedattribute.aspx

Comment: It depends on how you're building the add-in. Are you writing an *.xlam add-in using vba, or are you using another language to write a COM add-in?

Comment: doing it all in VBA. It looks like a reasonable approach is to use the Cached attributes or the worksheet.CustomProperties to hold the data. I was struggling because I couldn't figure out where to shove my stored data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings are stored in hidden names on the worksheet:

```
Sub Test()
Dim nName As Name
For Each nName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print nName.Name, nName.RefersTo
Next nName
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to confirm that solver uses hidden names, which is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cache attributes of the document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.runtime.cachedattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing to save more than 255 characters so hidden names would not work for me. So I ended up using worksheet custom properties which do not have the 255 char limit. My functions to save the state of a form then restore state ended up looking like this:

save state:

```
Private Sub save_form_state()
Dim prop As CustomProperty

    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        '' only saving state for text boxes and ref edits
        If TypeName(Control) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "RefEdit" Then
            '' only save state for controls with values -- custom properties can't have null values
            If Control.Value <> "" Then
                For Each prop In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.CustomProperties
                    '' if the name already exists in custom properties then delete it
                    If prop.Name = Control.Name Then prop.Delete
                Next prop
                '' any dupe has been deleted, so write the key and value
                ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.CustomProperties.Add Name:=Control.Name, Value:=Control.Value
            End If

        End If
    Next Control
End Sub
```

restore state:

```
Private Sub restore_form_state()
Dim prop As CustomProperty

    '' go through every text box and ref edit control then see if there's a custom property
    '' with matching name. If so, set the value of the control = custom property value
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Control) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "RefEdit" Then

            For Each prop In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.CustomProperties
                If Control.Name = prop.Name Then
                    Control.Value = prop.Value

                End If
            Next prop

        End If
    Next Control
End Sub
```